# While writing to S3, why I get FileNotFoundException

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Spark-SQL-2.3.1, Kafka, Java 8 in my project, and would like to use AWS-S3 as savage storage.

I am writing/storing the consumed data from Kafka topic into S3 bucket as below:

```
   ds.writeStream()
     .format("parquet")
     .option("path", parquetFileName)
     .option("mergeSchema", true)
     .outputMode("append")
     .partitionBy("company_id")
     .option("checkpointLocation", checkPtLocation)
     .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("25 seconds"))
     .start();
```

But while writing I am getting a `FileNotFoundException`

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory: s3a://company_id=216231245/part-00055-f4f87dc9-a620-41bd-9380-de4ba7e70efb.c000.snappy.parquet
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.s3GetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:1931)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.innerGetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:1822)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:1763)
```

I wounder why I'm getting `FileNotFoundException` when writing?  i am not reading from S3 right?
So what is happening here and how fix this?

Comment: What's happening is that there's checkpoints and multipart uploads. IDK why you would get it, but what version of each on lib are you using?

Comment: This is not a full stacktrace, is it? Also, what happens if you don't try to merge Parquet schema (schema merging begets reading)?

Comment: This is actually 404 caching causing surprises; a HEAD Request against a file made before it is created can be cached in the load balancers which then breaks a rename shortly afterwards. Not yet shipping versions of Hadoop are (slightly) Better, but to commit work safely you must use an s3a committer of the kind jegan discusses

Answer (score 2):

This is because S3 is not a file system, but an object store. It does not support the semantics required for rename like HDFS. Spark first writes the output files to temporary folder and then rename them. There is no atomic way of doing this in S3. That's why at times, you will see these errors.

Now, to fix this, if your environment allows, you could use HDFS as an intermediate storage and move the files to S3 for later processing.

If you are on hadoop 3.1, you could use s3a committers shipped with it. More details on how to configure this can be found [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/committers.html)

If you are on older version of hadoop, you could use an S3 output committer for Spark, which basically uses S3's multi-part upload to mimic this rename. One such committer I am aware of is [this](https://github.com/rdblue/s3committer). Looks like this is not updated recently though. There may be other options too.

Comment: the S3 committer you point to was actually pulled into Apache Hadoop 3.1; if your spark bundle has the hadoop 3.1 JARs, search for "S3A committer" and switch to it. EMR has its own "spark optimized committer" which does the same thing

Comment: @SteveLoughran you are right. I have updated the answer.